# (ChatterBot) Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, pycharm, chatterbot, certifi

I'm trying to use ChatterBot in PyCharm, but when running a simple example program:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

chatbot= ChatBot("Josie")

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

conversation = ["Hello","Hi There",
               "How are you doing?", "I'm doing great.",
               "That is good to hear", "Thank you.", "You're welcome."]

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train(conversation)

response = chatbot.get_response("Good morning!")
print (response)
```

I recieved this runtime error:

```
/Users/williams/PycharmProjects/test_1/venv/bin/python /Users/williams/PycharmProjects/test_1/test_1.py
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>
[nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: <urlopen error
[nltk_data]     [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
[nltk_data]     failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:1076)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/williams/PycharmProjects/test_1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 83, in __load
List Trainer: [######              ] 29%    root = nltk.data.find("{}/{}".format(self.subdir, zip_name))
 File "/Users/williams/PycharmProjects/test_1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 585, in find
   raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
 Resource stopwords not found.
 Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

 >>> import nltk
 >>> nltk.download('stopwords')

 For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

 Attempted to load corpora/stopwords.zip/stopwords/
```

I ran the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

but still got the error message "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>"

I've tried using  `/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command` but again I get an error:

[image]

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: should use `sudo` when installing something

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the user option:

> pip install --upgrade --user certifi